# On the fly custom domains using Rails + Nginx + Let’s Encrypt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, lets-encrypt

I have a Rails app that supports sub-domains right now. Users can have URLs like `abc.myapp.com`. The SSL is provided using Let’s Encrypt Wildcard Certificate for `*.myapp.com`.

Now, the app needs to be mapped to another domain according to the user’s preference. Like, users must be able to map `abc.myapp.com` to `hello.otherapp.com` With Let’s Encrypt.

Here are some references for what I am talking about:
https://support.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/227540-can-i-use-a-vanity-url-custom-domain-for-my-customer-portal-
https://help.canny.io/en/articles/1355038-setting-up-your-custom-domain

My stack is:
1. Ruby on Rails
2. Nginx
3. Let’s Encrypt

Answer (score -1):

You have 3 steps in general:

1. The DNS for your domain must have a wildcard, such as: `*.domain.com`
2. You must have a Web Server configuration using wildcards, for example using Nginx:

   ```
   server_name *.domain.com;
   ```

   documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html
3. Your Rails application must have in blueprint placed like `application_controller.rb` with code like

   ```
   User.find_by (subdomain: request.subdomain)
   ```

   and to read the path / route you must use `constraints`.

   documentation: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#request-based-constraints